# transform data with two time series columns

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I have data such that there are a set of identifier columns and then multiple time series values.

```
data.frame(id = c("x", "y", "z"),
             year_1_a = c(1, 2, 3),
             year_2_a = c(4, 5, 6),
             year_1_b = c(6, 7, 8),
             year_2_b = c(3, 4, 5), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I'm looking for a way to transform the data into a longer format where the ID would be duplicated, there would be a new column as a key and I would just have a single 'set' of years with values.

Expected output:

```
  data.frame(id = c("x","x", "y", "y", "z", "z"),
             key = c('a', 'b'),
             year_1 = c(1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8),
             year_2 = c(4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I was looking into `pivot_longer` but this renders the code too long with a row for each year and value. I'm thinking the best way is to split the data into two dfs and then `rbind` but was wondering if there was a better way without create intermediate data frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` by specifying the `names_sep` as the `_` which is followed by the letters at the end (`$`) of the name

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
out1 <- df %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -id, names_to = c('.value', 'key'), 
        names_sep="_(?=[a-z]$)")
out1
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  id    key   year_1 year_2
#  <chr> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 x     a          1      4
#2 x     b          6      3
#3 y     a          2      5
#4 y     b          7      4
#5 z     a          3      6
#6 z     b          8      5
```

-checking with OP's output

```
all.equal(out1, out, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or with `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
out2 <- melt(setDT(df), measure = patterns('year_1', 'year_2'),
      value.name = c('year_1', 'year_2'), variable.name = 'key')
```

---

Or with `reshape` from `base R`

```
reshape(df, idvar = 'id', direction = 'long', varying = list(c(2, 4), c(3, 5)))
```

Comment: Okay the `names_sep` argument seems to be the key here. As a regular expression follow up Q: How would you specify the last space in a string as the separator?

Comment: If you have space instead of `_`, then `names_sep = " (?=[a-z]$)")`

Comment: Awesome thank you. My issue was that I have a space and then characters within `()`. I had to escape the `()` first. I appreciate the different variations as well.

Comment: For that you can do `names_sep = " (?=\\()")`